# How to run multiple Tokio async tasks in a loop without using tokio::spawn?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I built a LED clock that also displays weather. My program does a couple of different things in a loop, each thing with a different interval:

- updates the LEDs every 50ms,
- checks the light level (to adjust the brightness) every 1 second,
- fetches weather every 10 minutes,
- actually some more, but that's irrelevant.

Updating the LEDs is the most critical: I don't want this to be delayed when e.g. weather is being fetched. This should not be a problem as fetching weather is mostly an async HTTP call.

Here's the code that I have:

```rust
let mut measure_light_stream = tokio::time::interval(Duration::from_secs(1));
let mut update_weather_stream = tokio::time::interval(WEATHER_FETCH_INTERVAL);
let mut update_leds_stream = tokio::time::interval(UPDATE_LEDS_INTERVAL);
loop {
    tokio::select! {
      _ = measure_light_stream.tick() => {
        let light = lm.get_light();
        light_smooth.sp = light;
      },
      _ = update_weather_stream.tick() => {
        let fetched_weather = weather_service.get(&config).await;
        // Store the fetched weather for later access from the displaying function.
        weather_clock.weather = fetched_weather.clone();
      },
      _ = update_leds_stream.tick() => {
        // Some code here that actually sets the LEDs.
        // This code accesses the weather_clock, the light level etc.
      },
    }
}
```

I realised the code doesn't do what I wanted it to do - fetching the weather blocks the execution of the loop. I see why - the docs of [`tokio::select!`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/macro.select.html) say the other branches are cancelled as soon as the `update_weather_stream.tick()` expression completes.

How do I do this in such a way that while fetching the weather is waiting on network, the LEDs are still updated? I figured out I could use [`tokio::spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/fn.spawn.html) to start a separate non-blocking "thread" for fetching weather, but then I have problems with `weather_service` not being `Send`, let alone `weather_clock` not being shareable between threads. I don't want this complication, I'm fine with everything running in a single thread, just like what `select!` does.

[Reproducible example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1f66f6451537304cb5c2aab3cb887da4)

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time::{interval, sleep};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut slow_stream = interval(Duration::from_secs(3));
    let mut fast_stream = interval(Duration::from_millis(200));
    // Note how access to this data is straightforward, I do not want
    // this to get more complicated, e.g. care about threads and Send.
    let mut val = 1;
    loop {
        tokio::select! {
          _ = fast_stream.tick() => {
            println!(".{}", val);
          },
          _ = slow_stream.tick() => {
            println!("Starting slow operation...");
            // The problem: During this await the dots are not printed.
            sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
            val += 1;
            println!("...done");
          },
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably using spawn is the best idea here. To communicate between tasks you can use mpsc channels. I miss such example in the tokio documentation as well. Maybe you could create an upstream issue to request exactly this kind of question. I strugle to find any information about this...

Comment: @hellow I would also spawn tasks, but OP says that `weather_service` doesn't implement `Send`, which makes tasks harder (without using something like [`spawn_local`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_local.html)). `weather_clock` likely _shouldn't_ be shared across tasks either.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: @Shepmaster Added example, although I don't really know what versions of things the playground is using. I believe it doesn't matter very much really.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`tokio::join!`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.17.0/tokio/macro.join.html) to run multiple async operations concurrently within the same task.

Here's an example:

```
async fn measure_light(halt: &Cell<bool>) {
    while !halt.get() {
        let light = lm.get_light();
        // ....

        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
    }
}

async fn blink_led(halt: &Cell<bool>) {
    while !halt.get() {
        // LED blinking code

        tokio::time::sleep(UPDATE_LEDS_INTERVAL).await;
    }
}

async fn poll_weather(halt: &Cell<bool>) {
    while !halt.get() {
        let weather = weather_service.get(&config).await;
        // ...

        tokio::time::sleep(WEATHER_FETCH_INTERVAL).await;
    }
}

// example on how to terminate execution
async fn terminate(halt: &Cell<bool>) {
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(10)).await;
    halt.set(true);
}

async fn main() {
    let halt = Cell::new(false);
    tokio::join!(
        measure_light(&halt),
        blink_led(&halt),
        poll_weather(&halt),
        terminate(&halt),
    );
}
```

If you're using `tokio::TcpStream` or other non-blocking IO, then it should allow for concurrent execution.

I've added a `Cell` flag for halting execution as an example. You can use the same technique to share any mutable state between join branches.

---

EDIT: Same thing can be done with `tokio::select!`. The main difference with your code is that the actual "business logic" is inside the futures awaited by `select`.

`select` allows you to drop unfinished futures instead of waiting for them to exit on their own (so `halt` termination flag is not necessary).

```
async fn main() {
    tokio::select! {
        _ = measure_light() => {},
        _ = blink_led() = {},
        _ = poll_weather() => {},
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of a `Cell` I would use a proper synchronization primitive, such as [`AtomicBool`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicBool.html)

Comment: @hellow since this is all done within the same thread `Cell` or `RefCell` is ok here.

Comment: I'll consider this. A downside is that all the loops need to finish their current sleep to realise halting happened, which means up to 10 minutes shutdown time, not really acceptable.

Comment: @TPReal I just realized that this code would also work with `select`, see the bottom part. Running concurrently in this case is more about just rearranging the code, than join/select.

Comment: And then you can add another branch in the form of e.g. `tokio::signal::unix::signal(...).recv()`, which will interrupt the whole thing nicely, and will actually be the only branch that can ever complete. Seems elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a concrete solution, based on the second part of stepan's answer:

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time::sleep;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // Cell is an acceptable complication when accessing the data.
    let val = std::cell::Cell::new(1);
    tokio::select! {
      _ = async {loop {
        println!(".{}", val.get());
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(200)).await;
      }} => {},
      _ = async {loop {
        println!("Starting slow operation...");
        // The problem: During this await the dots are not printed.
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        val.set(val.get() + 1);
        println!("...done");
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(3)).await;
      }} => {},
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c4d3651df5c072fb2bcd6dea41a611e4)